# Separating letters in file based on position

Tags: python, split, position

I have one .fa file with letters sequence like ACGGGGTTTTGGGCCCGGGGG and .txt file with numbers that show  start and stop position like start 2 stop 7. How could I extract  letters only from the specific positions  from my .fa file and create new file that will contain only letters from the assigned positions? I wrote such code but I got the error "string index out of range'' my position txtx file is just a lit with positions like [[1,52],[66,88].....

```
my_file = open('dna.fa')
transcript = my_file.read()
positions = open('exons.txt')
positions = positions.read()
coding_sequence = '' # declare the variable

for i in xrange(len(positions)):
    start = positions[i][0]
    stop = positions[i][1]
    exon = transcript[start:stop]
    coding_sequence = coding_sequence + exon
print coding_sequence `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your positions are stored in a list called `positions`, that the name of your infile is `infile.fa`, and the name of your outfile is `outfile.fa`:

```
with open("infile.fa") as infile:
    text = infile.read()
    letters = "".join(text[i] for i in positions)
    with open("outfile.fa", "w") as outfile:
        outfile.write(letters)
```

As has been mentioned in @KIDJourney's comment, this could theoretically fail for files large enough that there is not enough memory to store it.  Here is how you could do it if that is the case:

```
with open("infile.fa") as infile:
    with open("outfile.fa", "a") as outfile:
        outfile.seek(0)
        i = 0
        for line in infile:
            for char in line:
                if i in positions:
                    outfile.write(char)
                i += 1
```

Comment: What if the file is so large that RAM can't store it ?

Comment: I added a second solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this job with a VERY LARGE file , the solution of @zondo may failed something for the lack of RAM .

You can use [seek](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) when you are trying to read part of file .

```
def readData(filename , start_pos , end_pos):
    with open(filename) as f :
        f.seek(start_pos)
        data = f.read(end_pos - start_pos)
        return data
```